# Bjam for gcov coverage analysis?

Tags: c++, boost, code-coverage, gcov, bjam

I am looking to integrate a non-trivial cross-platform build system for a project predominately written in C++.  I've evaluated Cmake and Scons, so far, and while they both represent an improvement over (GNU) make, neither approach seemed either elegant or transparent in the
context I was trying to use these tools.  This brought me to Boost Build (Bjam) and I am encouraged that, given my project is dependent upon Boost, bjam should be available for any viable target platform
already.

I've run into difficulty trying to neatly integrate code-coverage for unit tests of a library...  with a view to eventual integration into a build server such as Jenkins.  While I'm willing to be guided by Bjam best/standard practice, I think I need three distinct "variants":

- release  - to build optimised static library only
- debug    - to build non-optimised static library and unit tests
- coverage - to build coverage-enabled library and link with non-coverage enabled unit tests.

Essentially, in addition to the standard debug and release builds, I'd like a special purpose debug build that also collects coverage data.

I need to build with (at least) g++ and msvc... and use gcov switches only with g++.  This means my library target needs different "compilerflags" to the unit-test executable target... and only for one of my compiler suites... and for only one variant.

I am unclear how best to achieve this with Bjam - though, I suspect, it should be a fairly common use case.  Does Bjam have explicit support for gcov coverage analysis (possibly presenting results
using lcov)?  If not, can anyone recommend a strategy which would support the above (simplified) scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident that the answer to your first question--whether bjam has explicit support for gcov--is a definite **no**, because like debug and release build configurations, bjam would consider that to be a [feature variant](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/builtins/features.html) for the user to define.

For bjam, it looks like there are a couple ways to do what you want:

1. [Define your own feature variant](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/20174/match=purecov) and then update the CONFIG_COMMAND for any custom flags.
2. [Define/redefine a toolset](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.build/20172/match=purecov).

For CMake, consider following the pattern that ITK does:

http://cmake.org/Wiki/ITK/Policy_and_Procedure_for_Adding_Dashboards#Configuring_GCOV_Coverage

Comment: Thanks for those pointers... I'd rather hoped that I'd find a sample that, at least, worked properly with gcc/gcov...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need and I basically added the lines below to define my own coverage variant in my Jamroot file.

```
variant coverage : debug : <cxxflags>--profile-arcs <cxxflags>--test-coverage <cxxflags>--coverage <link>shared ;
lib gcov : : <name>gcov : ;

unit-test mytest : tests/mytest.cpp libboost_unit_test : <variant>coverage:<library>gcov ;
```

The coverage data is created when the test is run and I exploit it afterward outside of bjam using gcov.